# Cucumber DataTables using 2 rows and 3 columns

Tags: java, datatables, cucumber, gherkin

Cucumber Java. I’m having issues trying to implement a step method using Data-tables with 2 rows and 3 columns.

```
    And I click on Build App form factors
  | IOS_SMARTPHONE_ADHOC | CLIENT_VERSION_4 | SUBCLIENT_VERSION_441 |
  | ANDROID_SMARTPHONE   | CLIENT_VERSION_4 | SUBCLIENT_VERSION_441 |
```

Here, I want to pass in each row as the 3 arguments. Not sure if thats how it works or if I have to switch it around. 
My method takes 3 arguments. I already built the method to function for a single execution. But I would like to do two app platforms in a single instance.

```
    @And("I click on Build App form factors")
public void clickOnFormFactors(DataTable dataTable) throws Exception {
    List<String> targets = dataTable.asList();
    List<Map<String, String>> clientVersions = dataTable.asMaps();
    List<Map<String, String>> subClientVersions = dataTable.asMaps();
    for (Map<String, String> target : clientVersions) {
        ActionPage.clickOnVersionsPerTarget(target, clientVersions, subClientVersion);
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure I'm using the loops and List initiation incorrectly. I was able to use asList() for 1column/2rows. I read that I need to use asMaps(). But no idea how to loop for 3 arguments to get data for the 3 columns.

Comment: For one, you need to give your table some column headers. Then you can reference a value in each row by the column header text.

Comment: I wasn't able to get my methods to work with using asmaps(); I used asList(). Then Used List<List<String>> so I can call columns.get(0), columns.get(1), columns.get(2) which was all I really needed to pass in the 3 args I had for my methods. Thanks! I just found out that asMaps() need headers! Good to know.